# Java; Initializing A Count of Input, After Period Is Entered

Tags: java, string

The instance of recognizing secondary input is non existent, after struggling to create an end of the line based on solo period input. Any help would be awesome.

```
***import java.io.*;
    public class Period
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException 
    { BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader
(new InputStreamReader (System.in));
String user, text;
int x , y , Z , Q;
x = 0;
Z = 0;
text = "";
y = 0;
Q = Z + y;
System.out.println ("Enter Charecters:");
user = stdin.readLine ();
for (y = user.length(); x != 1; Q = Z + y)
{
 if (user.endsWith(".") || text.endsWith ("."))
{
x = 1;
}
else
 text = stdin.readLine ();
 Z = text.length();
}
System.out.println("Total Charecters Entered:" + Q);
    }
}***
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more clear about what you're expecting to see and what you're getting instead?

Comment: We understand nothing :)

Comment: Welcome, it would be nice to indent the code correctly. And explain a bit more what your are trying to achieve and on what part your are struggling. See [ask] to get an idea of the question we await

Comment: *"The instance of recognizing secondary input is non existent of struggling to create an end ..."* - what?

Comment: Sorry new poster, basically the input prompt should end after the period is entered alone. I also created a count of both instance of user input entered and for total characters. These counts don't get picked up for any secondary or after the first input.

Comment: "_the input prompt should end after the period is entered alone_" This doesn't means much either. From what I see, you have a loop that will get a new `text` until it end with ".". You use a `for` loop where you should use a while loop since this is not readable to have those increment statement there.

Comment: The period works, its the count that won't initialize properly for secondary text inputs. The user variable is properly recorded for instance and length, this can't be said for the text variable.

Comment: I'm expecting a final output that says how many characters have been entered from both strings of input; text and user. The value of user and a period are the only one's that the code exports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your count variable is named `Q`. You increment it on each loop in the increment statement `Q = Z + y`

Where you have `Z` = `text.length();` and `y` = `user.length();`

Now, since you don't add those value to the previous `Q` value, you simply have `Z + y` so you only get the length of `user` and the last `text`, not the total count (correct me if I am wrong on the needs)

Use `Q = Q + Z + y` or `Q += Z + y` to increment correctly. (even if this should be done in the block statements, not in the for-increment part.

Note :

- Use **better variable name** : a one letter variable is usually restricted for a index like `int i`
- A `while` loop would fit better this logic : even if your loop is correct, a for loop is usually use to iterate a collection, not to hide some logic in it.
- if `user.endsWith(".") == true`, you will never prompt anything (correct)

A simpler version that should do the same if I get your code.

```
System.out.println ("Enter Charecters:");
int count = 0;
String text;
do{
    text = stdin.readLine();
    count += text.length;
} while(!text.endsWith("."));
```

Comment: @Xetius He did do the most part of the job with one incrementation problem. I just show him a better way to do it after pointing the problem... yes he will receive a better evaluation but I don't care about that, I just hope he will never write the first version of code EVER.